# How to choose log4j2 appender at runtime

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I use log4j **2.9**

I have file appenders configured in log4j2.xml.

**For example :**

```
 all_log_appender, device_appender, sql_appender
```

all appenders log in **different** files.

what is a  correct way to choose my appenders at runtime in order to decice where (in which file) to log?

To be honest I can't find examples in the documentation. I also [tried to extend Logger class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139885/why-cant-i-log-method-name-and-code-line-in-log4j-when-i-extend-log4j) but as I understand  [it's not correct to extend log4j2 logger class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34833747/2590960) because *"some layouts  require Log4j to walk the stacktrace to report which class and line in your code from the logger was called from"*

I can't find any examples how to choose appender at runtiime.

Could you give me a simple example please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be accomplished in configuration (no custom code required) by using the [Routing Appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) built in to Log4j2.

This appender can route log events to a set of predefined appenders or it can dynamically add new appenders if necessary. [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052070/log4j2-dynamic-creation-of-log-files-for-multiple-logs/19072195#19072195) has examples and links to other examples.

The manual page has three examples, but [the FAQ page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files) ("How do I dynamically write to separate log files?") has an example that uses the `ThreadContext` map to control which log file subsequent events (in the current thread) get logged to. (See also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279656/wildcard-pattern-for-routingappender-of-log4j2) on StackOverflow.)

Instead of the ThreadContext, it is also possible ([see LOG4J2-1015](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1015)) to route based on log event Markers, so the application can specify on a per-event basis which file appender the event is routed to. See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30266143/1446916) for an example that routes based on markers.