# Log4j2 left pad filename with zeroes

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

Is there a way to left pad with zeroes in the rolling file appender of log4j?

For instance myfile-00001.txt

I'm using a 3rd party log processor that reads files in lexicographical order so the the files must be left padded...

I added the following in the filePattern of log4j but I get spaces.

${logPath}/myfile-%05i.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log4j2 does not currently provide this out of the box. You can add a feature request on the log4j2 Jira issue tracker.

Meanwhile, as a workaround you can implement a custom lookup (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27418802/1446916) that generates a zero padded counter and use this in the filePattern of your RollingFile appender configuration.

Comment: This would be relatively easy to do.  The syntax would most likely be %i{format} where the format could be anything you could pass to String.format for an integer value.

Answer (score 2):

I created a [JIRA Ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2403) for this issue and also prepared a [pull request](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/224) that solves it. I would be glad if this was included in the next release of Log4j2.

Comment: Looks like the pull request was [accepted](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/224).