# How do I include a UNIX timestamp in a rolled log filename with log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

What I have now in my config file

```
{
    "type":"RollingFile",
    "name": "machineLog",
    "ThresholdFilter": { "level": "debug" },
    "JsonLayout":{"complete":"true"},
    "Policies":
    {
        "SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy": {"size":"100M"}
    },
    "fileName": "${sys:my.logging.directory}/machine.json",
    "filePattern":"${sys:my.logging.directory}/RolledLogs/$${date:yyyy}/$${date:MM}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-machine.json.gz"
}
```

I want the rolled file (`filePattern` entry) to contain a UNIX timestamp. Since this is legal I tried changing that line to be

```
"filePattern":"${sys:my.logging.directory}/RolledLogs/$${date:yyyy}/$${date:MM}/%d{UNIX}-machine.json.gz"
```

Figuring that since `%d{UNIX}` was mentioned in the [Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#Patterns) documentation page for `log4j2` it would work.

The result is that it creates the unrolled machine.json file but seems to not be able to append to it. It remains at zero bytes even when I flood the system with things that normally generates a ton of logs with the original config.

What's going on here? How can I achieve the effect I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can use all options of the PatternLayout %d date converter in the RollingFile filePattern.

However, if the `${sys:someKey...` system properties lookup works, then a custom lookup will also work. So one idea is to write a custom lookup plugin that generates the unix timestamp, and configure the RollingFile filePattern like this:
`"filePattern":"${sys:my.logging.directory}/RolledLogs/$${date:yyyy}/$${date:MM}/$${mylookup:UNIX}-machine.json.gz"`

Here is an example of how to write a custom Log4j 2 lookup plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27418802/1446916