# Log4j2 Property Replacement

Tags: log4j2

In Log4j2 appenders it's useful to use the contextPath as the filename, as in:
`filename="/logs/${web:contextPath}.log`.    This means one log configuration can be reused across multiple webapps.

However If a contextPath is `/foo/bar` this creates the file `/logs/foo/bar.log`.  Is there anyway to replace the `/` in the contextPath with `_` so the filename is `/logs/foo_bar.log`?

For me this is more useful than replicating the context path structure directly into the logs.  I 've read up on the [StringSubstitution](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/StrSubstitutor.html) docs and can't see anyway to do it, but if anyone has a solution it would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this out of the box. But you can easily create a custom lookup that does this.

Start by subclassing [WebLookup](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/dd943975b7c809c3d302237cecf7116c9c9e9ea2/log4j-web/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/web/WebLookup.java), and replace '/' characters with underscores in the returned string.

Example of creating a custom Log4j2 lookup: 
see the [manual page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Lookups), or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27418802/1446916).

Comment: Np. Let me know if there's any issue.